# С++20 циклическое импортирование модулей

Tags: c++, модули, c++20

Когда я в модуле A импортирую модуль B, а в модуле B импортирую модуль A, у меня возникает ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:
Module1:

```
export module Module1;

import Module;

export class B
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        A a;
        a.foo();
    }
};
```

Module:

```
export module Module;

import Module1;

export class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        B b;
        b.foo();
    }
};
```

main:

```
import Module;

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать такое импортирование, когда 2 модуля зависят друг от друга?

Comment: а Вы такое даже без модулей не сделаете. Вы не можете иметь два класса, каждый с которых содержит другой по значению.

Comment: @KoVadim я уже разобрался с проблемой, просто сделал .cpp файл, где реализовал метод из класса A

Answer (score 0):

ClassA.ixx

```
export module ClassA;

export class A
{
public:
    void bar();
};
```

ClassA.impl.ixx

```
import ClassA;
import ClassB;

void A::bar(){
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```

ClassB.ixx

```
export module ClassB;

import ClassA;

export class B
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        A a;
        a.bar();
    }
};
```

Test.ixx

```
export module Test;

import std.core;
using namespace std;

import ClassA;

export int main()
{
    A a;
    a.bar();
}
```

Произведёт SO.